# Trying to pad spaces on the right side of a string in SQL server and it's not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a csv file that is a set length, and therefore, the fields are a specific length. I'm trying the get my sql statement to pad these columns for me.

I've tried substring, left, space(xx), right, reverse, converting 'TEST' to a char value and I can't get this to work. I tried reverse knowing that using right (space(20) + 'TEST') got what I wanted but obviously was padded on the wrong side.

It seems that SQL server is just dropping the padded spaces on the right side of my string. The two below won't work. The length always comes back @ 4.

```
select len(reverse(right(space(20) + reverse('TEST'), 20)))

select len(left('TEST' + space(20), 20))
```

This one does work. But again, the spaces are on the wrong side.

```
select len(right(space(20) + 'TEST', 20))
```

This works too, and returns "TEST        1"

```
select len(left('TEST' + '        1', 20))
```

Again, it seems that as long as there is some real text on the right side of the string, it's fine.

Anyone have some ideas about how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because LEN ignores right padded spaces. You should use datalength instead.

```
select datalength(reverse(right(space(20) + reverse('TEST'), 20)))

select datalength(left('TEST' + space(20), 20))
```

Comment: I just found datalength before I came back and checked the post. Wish I would have known that a couple of hours ago. Thanks for the help.

Comment: +1 for datalength, did not know about that. I incorporated it in my answer for completeness, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @jpw Nope I don't mind at all. I was able to share some knowledge with two people at once. My day is now complete. I am going home now. :D

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for LEN:

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   excluding trailing blanks.

Thanks Sean Lange for pointing out the DATALENGTH method.

```
select 
    length = len('TEST' + space(20)), 
    datalength = datalength('TEST' + space(20)), 
    string = left('TEST' + space(20), 20)
```

will give the following output:

```
length      datalength  string
----------- ----------- --------------------
4           24          TEST
```

So as you can see the string has been padded up to 20 with blanks (or actually up to 24, but you only return 20 with LEFT), even though LEN will report length as 4.